# How to implement cascading DropDownList ASP.Net control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have code for a two `DropDownList` control, one that affects the elements in the other. The code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        FillDropDownList();
    }
}
```

I have set `AutoPostBack="True"` for newsletter `DropDownList`.

```
    private void FillDropDownList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select newsletter  FROM Tablename", connection Object);
        myda.Fill(ds);
        drop_date.DataSource = ds;
        drop_date.DataValueField = "date";
        drop_date.DataBind();
        drop_date.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
    }

    protected void drop_date_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select newsletter FROM tablename where date='"+drop_date.SelectedValue+"'",connection_Object);
        myda.Fill(ds);
        drop_newsletter.DataSource = ds;
        drop_newsletter.DataValueField = "newsletter";
        drop_newsletter.DataBind();
        drop_newsletter.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
    }
```

I think this code is correct, but I'm not sure how to apply this in the markup code using asp.net and html. How do I put that in? Or is there a javascript solution that is easier?

Comment: Are you saying you got this codebehind file from somewhere, but you don't have the markup to go with it?  If so, is that what you're asking for (someone to write the markup to go with this code)?

Comment: your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would use asp.net to create the dropdown list:

```
<asp:updatepanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <contenttemplate>
        <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="drop_date" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drop_date_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        </asp:dropdownlist>
        <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="drop_newsletter">
        </asp:dropdownlist>
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Then in your .cs code:

```
protected void drop_date_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter myda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select newsletter FROM tablename where date='"+drop_date.SelectedValue+"'",connection_Object);
    myda.Fill(ds);
    drop_newsletter.DataSource = ds;
    drop_newsletter.DataValueField = "newsletter";
    drop_newsletter.DataBind();
    drop_newsletter.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
    //This updates the panel Asynchronously
    UpdatePanel.Update();
}
```

If you were to use javascript:
you would need to create a webservice so you can use an ajax call to get your data back. Then you would bind that data to the 2nd dropdown list using javascript.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by applying it to the markup code, the way your code looks now you should have two drop down lists present on your form (in the source view) and when you select the first one (`drop_date`) it should post back and call `drop_date_SelectedIndexChanged()` (provided the `autopostback` property is set to true on `drop_date`).

A slicker way of doing this would be to consider one of the following:

- Consider using something like the Ajax Toolkit's [Cascading Drop Downs](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) controls. There's a full walkthrough for integrating it with a database [here](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/CCDWithDB.aspx).
- If you wanted to keep the above code another option is just to use an [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can read a tutorial for "Master/Detail Filtering With Two DropDownLists" (C#)

check that link : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-filtering-with-two-dropdownlists-cs