# How to keep DropDownList1 selected value after postback?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have two DropDownLists. Once a DropDownList1 value is selected, DropDownList2 will populate based on Dropdownlist1.

But after the page refreshes, the dropdownlist1 selected value is changed to the top-most value (the DropDownList is populate by a database).

.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="300px" CssClass="makeselect" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {      

    DataTable subjects = new DataTable();

    if (Page.IsPostBack == false) {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring)) {

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT VehicleMake FROM VehicleDB", con);
            adapter.Fill(subjects);

            con.Open();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = subjects;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "VehicleMake";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string makename = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    keepname = makename;

    Response.Redirect("default.aspx?QSVehicleMake="+makename);
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled ViewState? Then there should be no issue because the selected index is persisted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think he is "refreshing" the screen, hard to tell though, ViewState wont help him there.

Comment: Are you refreshing the page? Or actually posting back via AutoPostBack or a Submit button?

Comment: @mxmissile: but the selectedvalue should be the same even if you hit F5 in the browser. But he can't use `if(IsPostback)` because that will be `false` in that case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter true, OP should clarify.

Comment: @Charindu Edirisuriya Edit your question what you made changes so far

Comment: AutoPostBack is on.

Comment: After the page refresh, still the top most value is selected.

Comment: `DropDownList1.DataValueField = ""` if this is empty then Selected value will always return empty value, instead of this you can use `DropDownList1.DataValueField = "VehicleMake"` and put my Code after databind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SESSION value for this purpose, using this value you need to find Item from dropdown

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        jpyRATE = 1.4;

        DataTable subjects = new DataTable();

        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT VehicleMake FROM VehicleDB", con);
                adapter.Fill(subjects);

                con.Open();


                DropDownList1.DataSource = subjects;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "VehicleMake";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "VehicleMake";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();


                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["vehiclemake"] as string)) 
                {
                 DropDownList1.SelectedIndex =
                 DropDownList1.Items.IndexOf(DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(Session["vehiclemake"].ToString()));
                }


                con.Close();

            }

  }


    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string makename = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        keepname = makename;
        Session["vehiclemake"] = keepname;
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx?QSVehicleMake="+makename);
     }
```

Comment: BTW: `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["vehiclemake"]))` probably won't compile. Better use `if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["vehiclemake"] as string))` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

[How to implement cascading DropDownList ASP.Net control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052283/how-to-implement-cascading-dropdownlist-asp-net-control)

Don't `Response.Redirect()` to the same page in `SelectedIndexChanged()`.
It's better to put `DropDownList2` in an `UpdatePanel` to avoid full-page postback, which is the reason for `DropDownList1` being cleared.

Answer (score -1):

This might be because your dropdown is binding again at the time of postback. try below code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                    {
                               //write your dropdownlist1 binding code here
                    }

        }
```

Comment: I did it but it still happens

Comment: write a clean code.. make a function and write binding code inside.. And why DataValueField is assigned as blank. Anyway you should bind the ddl one time only so the code you write now should work.

Comment: In that case.. Please write you complete code including CS and aspx files

Comment: Check now?Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Are you redirecting again to same page? Response.Redirect("default.aspx?QSVehicleMake="+makename);

Comment: Yes, i am redirecting

Comment: To pass, the dropdownlist1 value.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ModelSelector1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DUTYCAL2016CON2 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [VehicleModel] FROM [VehicleDB] WHERE ([VehicleMake] = @VehicleMake)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="VehicleMake" QueryStringField="QSVehicleMake" 
                    Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: That's why the dropdown is binding again and again.. try comment the code out used for redirecting and try .